# In Hibernate, how to automatically retrieve parent id and use it in child insertion as foreign key?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

My desired action: *Inserting a row in the child table automatically inserts a row in the parent table if needed, otherwise use the id of the existing row in the parent table as the foreign key in the inserted row in the child table.*

I am wondering is there any way to do what is mentioned above in hibernate using a single `session.save(child)` statement.

I am using Hibernate with Java and SQLite.
Below are my specifics of the DB and the configuration:

Table Parent :

```
{id (int): primary key, description (text): unique}
```

Table Child :

```
{id(int): primary key, address (text), parent_id (integer): foreign key refers Parent(id)}  [UNIQUE ( address, parent_id )]
```

POJO Parent :

```
{int id, String description, Set<Child> children, [getters and setters] }
```

POJO Child :

```
{int id, String address, Parent parent, [getters and setters]}
```

Parent.hbm:

```
...
<id column="id" name="id" type="long">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property column="description" name="description" type="string" unique="true" />
<set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="children" table="Child">
    <key>
        <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
...
```

Child.hbm:

```
....
<id column="id" name="id" type="long">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property column="address" name="address" type="string"/>
<many-to-one cascade="save-update" class="Parent" fetch="select" name="parent">
    <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
...
```

As of now, parent is inserted along with child if parent (with the same 'description') does not exist. Otherwise, child is not inserted as parent insertion fails because of unique 'description' requirement.

Since I do not know the id of the parent while inserting a child ( I only know the description of the parent), I cant do a session.load(Parent.class, parentId) to retrieve the parent object and use it to insert child. What I am doing now is the following:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setDescription("D1");

Child child = new Child();
child.setAddress("A1");

parent.getChildren().add(child);
child.setParent(parent);
session.save(child);
```

I know I can always look up the parent id first by executing a query `select id from Parent where description="D1"` and then if the resultset is empty, save the child as I am doing it now (which inserts the parent as well), and if the result is not empty, use `session.load()` to load the parent object and use it to insert the child. But I thought hibernate can handle that for me behind a single `session.save(child)`. Can it?

Comment: I am having same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps;

1.Change your Parent.hbm

```
 ...
<id column="id" name="id" type="long">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property column="description" name="description" type="string" unique="true" />
<set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="children" table="Child" cascade="save-update">
    <key>
        <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</set>
...
```

2.Change your Child.hbm

```
....
<id column="id" name="id" type="long">
   <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property column="address" name="address" type="string"/>
<many-to-one class="Parent" fetch="select" name="parent">
    <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
...
```

3.And add child before parent as you want

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setDescription("D1");

Child child = new Child();
child.setAddress("A1");
child.setParent(parent);

session.save(child);
Set<Child> childsSet = new HashSet<Child>();
childsSet.add(child);

parent.setChildren(childsSet);
session.save(parent);
```

Comment: Works when there is no row in Parent with the description, but it fails in subsequent insertion of a child (with different address) associated with parent with the same description (unique column description needed). The latter case is the more common scenario in my application where children will be inserted with already existing parent, but sometimes it can have a parent that does not exist in the db yet, in that case the parent needs to be inserted as well. I want the application logic to be free from knowing these cases by using a single `session.save(child)` (or `session.save(parent)` )